# Populate custom listview when I click on another custom listview item

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, custom-adapter

I have two listviews with custom adapters. The first listview contains names of lists. When I click on the name of a list, the second listview have to be populated with the contents of the clicked list. I need to read the contents of the list from a local SQLite database that's located in assets, but that's not important. Assume that I have array of the contents. I know how to do this if I have to populate them on button click, but I don't know to do it this way. Both listviews are in the same activity.

Comment: u should implement onclicklistener or itemclicklistener and then on click of the first listview get the data from sqlite database and fill ur array by that data and then setlistAdapter()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using **onItemClickListener** of **listview** u can do this.

on **onitemclickListener** of first **listview** u set adapter for the second **listview**

u can do this using one **customadapetr** and u can write separate **customadapter** for both

**listview**.

if u post some sample code i will try to give more specific answer